# Is there anything I can do when my Canon DSLR is dead even on a full battery?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting

Today i was trying to click a macro image with my Canon 100 mm macro and 70D in live view and using an external flash when my camera suddenly went dead. I think it gave an err80 before completely dying out. I have searched over the net and found two causes:

1. Motherboard and PCB fried; that is going to cost a ton of $$
2. Some sensors on battery compartment being fragile and some issue with sensor position (tried rectifying the position but no help)

Last option is to go to service center and get help but wanted to know if anyone in this forum faced a similar issue that might help.

Some observations

1. Camera gives no indications of being alive.
2. Viewfinder appears dark when battery is not inserted.

Camera worked perfectly for last almost three years and I have taken it to places. It has never been dropped. Feeling sad as its dead now hopefully it gets back in shape after servicing.

Comment: SMALL hope. Measure battery voltage with a voltmeter. If 3 terminals it's usually the outer 2. Will be over 8V if fully charged and about 6V if fully discharged. If the battery has died the voltage may be 0V or under 6V. BUT it's probably a job for an expert. Where are you located?

Comment: The + and - contacts on the LP-E6 battery used by the 70D are marked + and -, but they are in two narrow recessed slots that traditional voltmeter leads will not fit into. The two easily accessed contacts marked T and C are for electronic communication only.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions .. Already mentioned it "Some sensors on battery compartment being fragile and some issue with sensor position" (tried rectifying the position but no help) -- Already tried this about sensor position from a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYlNyZ1IP3s .. No loss in springness ..

Comment: Gave my camera for repair. Service center notified that the motherboard unit is damaged as i had mentioned above. So this issue is not a duplicate of "Why is my Canon 300D not switching on despite changing both batteries and the CF card? ".

Comment: What external flash? Anything with an old school HV trigger circuit?